# How to describe different ways of writing the same cycle $(a\;b\;c)=(b\;c\;a)=(c\;a\;b)$?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$. Now consider a $3$-cycle of $A$, 
$$\alpha=(1\;2\;3)=(2\;3\;1)=(3\;1\;2).$$

Is there a word or phrase to describe the respect in which these ways of writing $\alpha$ differ? We could say they are different permutations of $A$, but I'd like this to be expressible as a property of $\alpha$.

For instance, are these three different *orderings* of $\alpha$?

Comment: You can write the permutations as $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3$ , the multiplication of permutations means applying them one after the other.

Comment: @Peter Wouldn't $\alpha^2$ give $(1\;3\;2)=(2\;1\;3)=(3\;2\;1)$, a different cycle?

Comment: Let us take $\alpha=(231)$. Then 1->2 , 2->3 , 3->1. If we apply this again, we have 2->3 , 3->1 , 1->2 (hence we get (312) and then we get 3->1,1->2,2->3 (123). You can identify the permutations as elements of the symmetric group $S_3$. Viewed this way, the $3$-cycle generates a subgroup of order $3$.

Comment: @Peter Is my initial equation, $(1\;2\;3)=(2\;3\;1)=(3\;1\;2)$, wrong? If it's right then your description would seem to give us $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \; \alpha=\alpha^n$.

Comment: Permuting in the direction 1->2 , 2->3 , 3-> 1 and so on, cannot give (132) , to get all permutations, we also need , for example a trasposition (which (213) is because it swaps 1 and 2 and lets 3 in its place). We say that (123) and (12) generate the permutations with $3$ elements, the group $S_3$

Comment: @mjc you are correct.

Comment: Do you want a notation for the cycle (in which case it does not matter where we start) or the element/permutation (in which case it does matter) ?

Comment: @Peter The way I understand it, $\text{cycles}\in\text{permutations}\in\text{functions }f:A\mapsto A$, and there are $n$ ways of writing a given $n$-cycle, reflecting the fact that it doesn't matter where you start. I'd like a way to describe the different ways of writing. Chris Custer's answer of 'cyclically permuting the elements of $\alpha$' sounds like it might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: And what does "123" mean for you ? the idendity permutation or 1->2 , 2->3 , 3->1 ? both approaches are used, so we have to clarify that.

Comment: @Peter By $(1\;2\;3)$ I mean $1\mapsto 2, \; 2\mapsto 3, \; 3\mapsto 1$, your second option. For the identity permutation I would write $(1)(2)(3)=(2)(3)(1)=\text{etc.}$

Comment: In fact, we can enumerate all the possible permutations (meaning the same cycle), by applying the cycle repeatedly, so "cyclically permuting" is in fact basically what you want.

Comment: @Peter I think there must still be some difference in our use of terms, because the way I understand it applying a cycle repeatedly gives a different cycle, not a different way of writing the same cycle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107964/discussion-between-peter-and-mjc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called cyclically permuting the elements of $\alpha$.  They give equivalent ways of writing it. 
 There are $n$ ways to do this for a given $n$-cycle.

Comment: This seems promising, but I'm not sure I'm all the way there. If $\alpha$ is a permutation function then (at least the way I understand functions) it is not a set and so has no elements. Are we thinking of $\alpha$ as the set of mappings $\{1\mapsto 2,\;2\mapsto 3,\;3\mapsto 1\}$, so that permuting its elements means permuting those mappings, with purely notational effect?

Comment: Take $\alpha=(123)$.  There are three ways to write it.  Namely, $(123),(231)$ and $(312)$.  That's all.  So for an $n$- cycle there are $n$ ways.

Comment: I'm fine with that bit. But by "the elements of $\alpha$" do you mean "the elements in the domain of $\alpha$"?

Comment: You're correct.  I use the term slightly loosely here.  Take it in context.  Everything is in the domain of $\alpha$.  But technically I mean the elements that $\alpha$ "moves".

Comment: Could we say we're permuting the decomposition of $\alpha$? That is, $(1\;2\;3)=(2\;3\;1)=(3\;1\;2)=(1\mapsto 2)\circ (2\mapsto 3) \circ (3\mapsto 1)$, so $(1\;2\;3)$, $(2\;3\;1)$ and $(3\;1\;2)$ are permutations of $\{(1\mapsto 2),(2\mapsto 3),(3\mapsto 1)\}$.

Comment: There's enough 'lingo' floating around, and I'd rather not complicate things. But I guess I see what you mean, as an $n$-cycle is decomposed.  Again, and you said you're fine with it, they are different representations of, or ways of writing, the same permutation.  We are just writing it in a different form.